# coffeescript: jquery click function only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, coffeescript

I've searched for an answer and can't find one that works.

Basically I have a function that posts to a facebook wall or a twitter feed, but the click function only fires once.

Here's the code:

```
$('.social a').on 'click', (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    book = book.collectMeta $(@).parents('.book')

    if $(@).hasClass 'fb-share'
        postFacebook book

    if $(@).hasClass 'twitter-share'
        postTwitter book
```

My collectMeta function that gets fired is this:

```
book = 
    collectMeta: (dom) ->
        # Helper function that collects data of a book and prepares it 
        # for sharing on sociall media

        # The argument for this function accepts the parent DOM Object
        # that searches for the appropriate Meta Data

        $title = dom.find '.book-title'
        title = helper.cleanWhite $title.text()

        $author = dom.find '.book-author'
        author = helper.cleanWhite $author.text()

        $description = dom.find '.book-description'
        description = helper.cleanWhite $description.text()
        description = helper.trimText(description, 140)

        $link = dom.find '.book-link'
        link = glob.baseUrl() + $link.attr 'href'

        $image = dom.find '.book-image'
        image = glob.baseUrl() + $image.attr 'src'

        return book = 
            title: title
            caption: author
            description: description
            link: link
            image: image
```

And the error I receive after the first click, which works, is:
book.collectMeta is not a function

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first click is calling a function that doesn't exist: `book.collectMeta`. This is killing your script, so nothing after that will work.

It looks to me like this might be happening because you are overriding the book variable in this line:

```
 book = book.collectMeta $(@).parents('.book')
```

So the first click will work, but later ones will not because book no longer has a function associated with it.